# How to lift a value into a Future

Tags: scala

Sometimes, we have to lift a value into a `Future`.

Here are 2 ways to do that :

- Solution 1 : `def lift[T](t: T) : Future[T] = Future(t)`
- Solution 2 : `def lift[T](t: T) : Future[T] = Future.successful(t)`

As far as I know, solution 2 seems to be more performant because it avoid threading mechanism and maybe *context switching*.

Are there another pro and cons ?
Are there another solution ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the value you need to wrap into a future is already computed (which is implied since `t: T` is not passed by-name, thus is already known), then option 2 is the way to do that, hands down.

Option 1 involves a context switch which may actually slow down the performance.

However, sometimes you need to perform several inexpensive in-memory computations (such as parameter validation, without IO), and want a `Future` as a result. `Future.successful(throw new Exception)` doesn't produce a Future, but throws the exception - this may be unexpected, as we tend to handle Futures as a language construct with its distinguished flow of execution, and don't generally handle synchronous exceptions in asynchronous code. To protect yourself from this situation, consider another option:

```
def lift[T](t: => T): Future[T] = Future.fromTry(Try(t))
```

By-name argument will defer the computation until it's wrapped in a Try, transforming an exception, if it occurs, into a `Future.failed` instead of throwing it.